# How do I automatically create service principals or MSIs with Terraform for use in Azure Pipelines to manage AKS resources?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm [following the official docs to create Azure Kubernetes clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-k8s-cluster-with-tf-and-aks). The docs state that I need to create a service principal first, manually, and provide the client_id and client_secret.

Doing it manually is not an option.

Here is the code for my service principal. It's decorated with links to the most recent Terraform docs for reference.

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "random_id" "current" {
  byte_length = 8
  prefix      = "ExternalDnsTf"
}

# Create Azure AD App.
# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application
resource "azuread_application" "current" {
  display_name = random_id.current.hex
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]

}

# Create Service Principal associated with the Azure AD App
# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.current.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

# Create Service Principal password
# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_password
resource "azuread_application_password" "current" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.current.object_id
}

# Create role assignment for service principal
# https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "current" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"

 # When assigning to a SP, use the object_id, not the appId
 # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli
  principal_id = azuread_service_principal.current.object_id
}
```

I keep getting the following error in my pipeline: (note, I am the owner of my subscription)

```
ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData
│ error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
│ operation.
```

What I'm trying to do is to eliminate the manual steps to setup supporting services. Take ExternalDNS for example. [The Azure docs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/azure.md) state that I need to use `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n ExternalDnsServicePrincipal; az role assignment create --role "Reader" --assignee <appId GUID> --scope <resource group resource id>; az role assignment create --role "Contributor" --assignee <appId GUID> --scope <dns zone resource id>`

**Ultimately, I'm trying to create the terraform version of the azure cli commands.**

Support for `create-for-rbac` [was a feature request on github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/40#issuecomment-477076926). That used to work great, but so much has changed, it's not applicable to current API versions. Also, with AAD Graph being deprecated in favor Microsoft Graph API, I wonder if I'm getting snagged on that.

The ExternalDNS docs also suggested Managed Service Identities (MSI). Service principals, MSI, MSGraph API integration, honestly, I don't care which one is used. Whatever is current best-practices is fine **so long as I do not have to log into the portal to manually create or give permissions, or manually run `az cli` commands.**

**EDIT: Permissions clarification**

I'm using Terraform, of course, to provision resources. If I do all of this without terraform (manually or with a bash script), I use `azure cli` I start setting permissions by doing the following:

- `az login`
- `az account set -s <my-subscription-id>`

I am the owner of my subscription. I can run all commands, create SPs, MSIs, assign roles, etc, with no problem.

In the pipelines, [I am using the charleszipp az pipelines terraform](https://github.com/charleszipp/azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform) plugin. In the logs, I see:

- `az login --service-principal -t <my-tenant-id> -u *** -p ***`
- `az account set -s <my-subscription-id>`

I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I interpret that as ultimately, commands are executed after signing in and setting the account subscription, like I do manually.

Technically, I'm not using a service connection in several of these tasks. However, where one is required, I have created a Service connection and defined its Scope to the subscription level. It's of type Azure Resource Manager.

However, if I click "manage service principal, it takes me to the portal where there are no permissions defined.

While I am the owner of my subscription, I am not the root management group. I'm owned / provisioned by someone else. Ultimately, they have control of Active Directory. I cannot add or edit permissions. If I try to add any under permissions API and select Microsoft Graph, it says that authorization is required. `Grant Admin Consent for <parent organization` is greyed out.

But why would that be important if I'm the owner of my subscription? If I can do whatever I want via the az cli command line, what's preventing me from doing the same in the pipeline?

Comment: I guess you are using Service connection in Azure pipelines, what is your permission level in the subscription ,  ? like owner or contributor ?

Comment: and what Microsoft Graph API permissions does the Service connection have ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Please see the EDIT above for permissions clarification. I own my subscription. There is a parent organization that maintains control of Active directory. I cannot Grant Admin Consent in Permissions API. All Service connections in the Pipeline are Scoped at the Subscription level are are of type Azure Resource Manager. Do I need a different connection type?

Answer (score 2):

I am using user-managed identity for that, it seemed most straightforward and worked fine for me.

```
resource "azurerm_user_managed_identity", "mi" {
    resource_group_name = "rg"
    name = "mi"
    location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ra" {
    scope = azurerm_subnet.sn.id  // subnet I created earlier
    role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"  // required with kubenet
    principal_id = azurerm_user_managed_identity.mi.principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
    name = "aks"
    identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_managed_identity.mi.id
    }
    <...remaining attributes...>
    depends_on = [azurerm_role_assignment.ra] // just to be safe
}
```